# VBs to log (.txt) telnet output

Tags: vbscript

A very simple script to save time for something i (repeatedly) need to check @ work;

```
Set cloner = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
cloner.SendKeys"telnet 0.0.0.0"  
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")  
WScript.Sleep 1000  
cloner.SendKeys("whatever")
```

And, i'd like this to output to a .txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
Set cloner = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 cloner.Run "cmd.exe"
 WScript.Sleep 1000
 cloner.SendKeys"telnet 0.0.0.0 -f out.txt"
 cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
 WScript.Sleep 1000
 cloner.SendKeys("whatever")
```

Comment: text output doesn't seem to work for telnet like this, i'm on it.

Comment: i found the solution, it's -f parameter of telnet.exe

Answer (score 0):

The code just producing a blank txt; no string in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run("telnet.exe")  
WScript.Sleep 500

WshShell.SendKeys("set logfile filename.txt{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

WshShell.SendKeys("open 0.0.0.0{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

WshShell.SendKeys("whatever")
```

this will create a file named filename in the working directory, can be replaced with absolute path aswell.