# VBS issue with SendKeys when tried to get a value and save on Dim variable

Tags: variables, vbscript, telnet, sendkeys

I need some help with a VBS script.
I want use a VBS script to access a router via telnet and save the value of a parameter on the router to a Dim variable.

The problem is that the DIM variable doesn´t save the output of the router parameter.

This is my script:

```
option explicit

DIM x

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe"

WScript.Sleep 500

oShell.SendKeys "telnet 192.168.1.254"
oShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 500

oShell.SendKeys "Administrator"
oShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 500

oShell.SendKeys ""
oShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 500

x = oShell.SendKeys ("env get var=_SW_FLAG") and oShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}") 

WScript.Sleep 500

oShell.SendKeys "exit"
oShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 500

oShell.SendKeys "exit"
oShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 500

MsgBox "The value of the parameter is:" & x
```

Comment: To format code blocks in a post, you should indent by four spaces, not make each line separate...

Comment: Comment: `Dim` is the instruction in VB to create a variable. There is no such a thing as *DIM variables*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads like [this](http://www.mofeel.net/902-microsoft-public-scripting-vbscript/17104.aspx) make me think that the particular detail of getting the output is not possible with the approach you have.

The closest I could get is this previously asked question: [vbs to log (.txt) telnet output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8260702/422353)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I did this using a .text file (as you suggested)